# WordPress ACF Relation field loop out pages

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a Relation field to create a little menu with a few links in it.
I've selected my pages and wrote the loop with the help of the documentation provided on the ACF website. The problem is the loop doesn't seem to be working. I get no errors and there's nothing to see, when I try to debug and dump the variable that is supposed to get the data it says NULL.

Anyone knows what is going wrong here? Been trying to fix it for multiple days now :/

Here's my loop:

```
<?php 

    $posts = get_field('field_56ebc552c03cb');

    if( $posts ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Try to rename variable `$posts` to `$menu_posts`

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, still gives NULL when I try to dump it

Comment: I think the problem comes from this function `get_field('field_56ebc552c03cb')`,incorrect parameters or incorrect post ID, check again parameters

Comment: The field ID is correct

Comment: Thats wrong, please view this article [link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), function `get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value);` first parameter is $field_name not field ID

Comment: Field name or field key it's the same I use it all the time. I've tried with field name doesn't work either :)

Comment: Check current post / page ID is equally with this on page.

Comment: @htmlbrewery I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say here

Comment: @FrankLucas Are you calling this within the Loop? If not you'll need to provide `get_field` with an ID for the post/page/etc.

Comment: @Emil I am not calling this within the Loop, how am I supposed to provide the get_field with an ID? I have no idea what ID I should use or where to find one

Comment: @FrankLucas Well, ACF works by adding extra fields to posts, pages and other types of content in Wordpress, so if you want to display data from a field, that data is connected to a post, which has a post ID.

Comment: @Emil Can you checkout edited OP I've added a screenshot of my code

Comment: @FrankLucas First off, please don't screenshot and post code like that, copy-past it in instead. Secondly, I don't understand what you are trying to do – where are you setting the data you want to retrieve using the `get_field`-function? You cannot call `get_field` without an ID parameter unless you're in the loop, because `get_field` retrieves data connected to a post.

Comment: I have created an options page with acf, there you can select the pages you want to add to the "footer_links", "footer_links is an extra field you can edit in the options page

Comment: @Emil I am actualy an idiot wauw, shouldn't I use something like this '$menu_posts = get_field('footer_links', 'option');' since it's a field in my options page?

Comment: try using the field_name instead the field ID .. then dump $posts

Comment: @PrakashRao Thanks for you input, but I have found the problem. You can check out my answer if you're interested

Comment: ohhh .. that's great

Answer (score 0):

I' ve found the issue, since I am using a field in my custom options page to retrieve the data I should use this:

> $menu_posts = get_field('footer_links', 'option');

And my loop should look like this:

```
<?php 

    $menu_posts = get_field('footer_links', 'option');

    if( $menu_posts ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $menu_posts as $p ): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```